# How to export the results of anova in R to an excel file?

Tags: r, anova

```
# Create Excel Files for Linear Regression and StepAIC
MyExcelFile <- XLConnect::loadWorkbook("Anova_Results.xlsx", create = TRUE)


#Build the Regression model
LinReg_Model<-function(x) {
  Countries <- c("abc,def,ghi")
  for (val in Countries) {
    createSheet(MyExcelFile, val) 
    #create a sheet and name it with country name 
    set.seed(111)
    LinReg <- lm(Sales ~.,data=datadf)
    Lin_Anova <- anova(LinReg)
    writeWorksheet(MyExcelFile1, Lin_Anova, sheet = val, startRow = 1, startCol = 1) # write results of Model Summary
    }
  saveWorkbook(MyExcelFile1) 
  }

# run the function to check
LinReg_Model()
```

After running the above code I do get the results, however the excel sheet does not capture the names of the variable as seen in the attached image.
FYI, I am using XLConnect package for writing the data in to excel. 
 [image]

Comment: I think it's because the variable names are stored as row names. There should be an option to keep the row names in your excel file. Otherwise you can use the `broom` package. Add the command `tidy(Lin_Anova)` which will create a data frame with the variable names stored as a column. You can save that data frame as an excel file.

Comment: That solved my issue. Thanks